# Text to be translated not recognized in mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

```
Rails 3.2
```

In my config/locales/en.yml, I have:

```
mailers:
  message_notifier:
    notify_admin_subject: ' added a comment to ticket '
    user_name: 'User: '
    email_address: 'Email: '
    company_name: 'Company: '
    added_following_comment: 'Added the following comment: '
    to_ticket: 'To Ticket: '
```

In my app/mailers/message_notifier.rb, I have the following:

```
def notify_admins_when_ticket_has_new_comment(comment)
  @global_admin = User.find("global-admin")
  email_to = @global_admin.email
  @user = User.find(comment.user_id)
  msg = [t(mailers.message_notifier.user_Name) + @user.first_name + ' ' + @user.last_name]
  msg << (t(mailers.message_notifier.email_address) + @user.email)
  msg << (t(mailers.message_notifier.company_name) + @user.company.name)
  msg << (t(mailers.message_notifier.added_following_comment) + @comment.content)
  @ticket = Ticket.find(@comment.commentable_id)
  msg << (t(mailers.message_notifier.to_ticket) + @ticket.number)
  plain_msg = ''
  html_msg = ''
  msg.each do |m|
    plain_msg = plain_msg + m + '\n'
    html_msg = html_msg + m + "<br>"
  end
  subject = @user.email + (t(mailers.message_notifier.notify_admin_subject)) + @ticket.number
  mail(to: email_to, subject: subject) do |format|
    format.text { render text: plain_msg.html_safe }
    format.html { render text: html_msg.html_safe }
  end
end
```

But, I am getting the following error message:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `mailers' for #<MessageNotifier:0x007faf5f540810>):
app/mailers/message_notifier.rb:24:in `notify_admins_when_ticket_has_new_comment'
```

Reading through the I18n API docs, I was under the impression, that this is the proper way to do it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful with the syntax: `t("mailers.message_notifier.user_name")` instead of `t(mailers.message_notifier.user_Name)`. Notice that the arguments to the `t` method need to be strings, and that uppercase/lowercase matters when you define translation keys.

Comment: This worked. Is there a better way to do the translate call? I had another issue, where I forget to explicitly do a to_s on number (integer).

Comment: I'm not sure what better would mean - this is how the `I18n.t` method works. Regarding the other problem, you always have to pay attention to the type of the objects you're using.